# GraphQL.Net List of int as argument

Tags: graphql-dotnet

I am trying to build an application using .Net and GraphQL. I need to get materials. not all of them but with the given Ids. When I pass it via playground or client side, I don't have any problem when I debug but I am not sure how to parse in the server side.

```
                name: "materialsByIds",
                arguments: new QueryArguments(
                            new QueryArgument<ListGraphType<IntGraphType>> { Name = "ids"}),
                resolve: async (context) =>
                {
                    var ids = context.GetArgument<IntGraphType>("ids");
                    // Do some action to bring datas
                    // Send data back
                }
```

What am I missing here is there any methods to parse this in to list of int back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a GraphType for retrieving the argument, use the .NET type you want.

```
name: "materialsByIds",
arguments: new QueryArguments(
               new QueryArgument<ListGraphType<IntGraphType>> { Name = "ids"}),

resolve: async (context) =>
{
    var ids = context.GetArgument<List<int>>("ids");
    // Do some action to bring datas
    // Send data back
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `MediatR`. Create a Query class and pass it to mediateR. In `CQRS`, Command is used to write on DB(Create/Delete/Update of CRUD) and Query is used to read from DB(Read of CRUD).

create `'GetMaterialsByIdsQuery'` and inside it write your code to get your materials by Id. then use it inside `'resolve'` like this:

```
resolve: async context =>
             {
               var ids = context.GetArgument<List<int>>("ids");             
               return await mediator.Send(new GetMaterialsByIdsQuery(ids));
             })
```

another way is that you can return somthing like  `MaterialsRepository.GetMaterialsByIds(ids)` instead of using mediatR. But it is not recommended to use repository here. you can create a service class, inside it use your repository and then use your service here.

Comment: I am using MediatR in the project already. We were getting the materials one by one.  I have created the mediatR and business implementation already. I was looking how to get a list of Ids from a query. The answer one above worked. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: you're welcome. joe has said true! i have copied your code to just saying about MediatR and i haven't seen the mistake about IntGraphType. I have edited it now.